# How to implement Angular Drop-down with Search

Tags: json, angular, angularjs, rxjs

How to do a drop-down with search. I don't know how to implement the search here in my drop down. hoping someone can help me. I can do the dropdown with search if the data I'm getting is static.

here in my code, the data I'm supplying in my drop is dynamic supplier: SupplierDTO[]; This (supplier) is my created model wherein I'm fetching the fields I need.

.html

```
<mat-form-field class="box" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Supplier</mat-label>

<mat-select formControlName="supplierId" (selectionChange)="selectedSupplier($event)">
<mat-option *ngFor="let items of supplier" [value]="items.id">
{{items.companyName}}
</mat-option>
                                
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
export class DeliveryReceiptComponent implements OnInit {

supplier: SupplierDTO[];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.selectedSupplier;
}

selectedSupplier(trigger: MatSelectChange)
  {
      this.selectedSupplierID = trigger.value;
      this.supplierSvc.getSupplierDR(this.selectedSupplierID).subscribe((response: any) => {
          
          var splitted = response.split(":", 4)
          this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('Bank').patchValue(splitted[0]);
          this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('AccountName').patchValue(splitted[1]);
          this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('AccountNumber').patchValue(splitted[2]);
          this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('Branch').patchValue(splitted[3]);
          if(this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('AccountName').value === this.dbmRequired ){
            this.APRDisplayed = true;
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseRequestNumber').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseRequestDate').addValidators(Validators.required);             
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('drNumFrSupplier').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('drDate').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('aprNum').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('aprDate').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseOrderDate').setValue('0001-01-01');
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('saleInvoiceDate').setValue('0001-01-01');
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('aprDate').reset();
          }
          else{
            this.APRDisplayed = false;
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseOrderNumber').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseOrderDate').addValidators(Validators.required); 
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseRequestNumber').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('purchaseRequestDate').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('saleInvoiceDate').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('saleInvoiceNumber').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('drNumFrSupplier').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('drDate').addValidators(Validators.required);
            this.deliveryReceiptForm.get('aprDate').setValue('0001-01-01');

          }
      })
     
  }
```

Comment: What is the data structure of the response?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your response is not an array, but an object instead. Therefore you should map the following:

```
getData(){
  return this.http.get('https://localhost:44350/api/EamisDeliveryReceipt/list')
    .pipe(
      map(response  => response.items.map(suppliers => suppliers.supplier.companyName)
    )
  )
}
```

Hint: You should probably define an interface for the type returned by this API. This way it's way easier to perform any mapping on the data.

Comment: I think i got an error in: response.items

Comment: Can you provide any information on this error?

Comment: Property 'items' does not exists on type 'Object'. ts(2339)

Comment: Well, then maybe your screenshot of your JSON data retrieved by this API is not correct? In the screenshot I can definitely see that this property does exist.